# What's a better way to say please forgive my lack of knowledge in your profession?

Tags: figures-of-speech

I don't know anything about the law and I'm trying to write to a court appointed attorney to explain the tardiness of my letter.

Comment: Welcome! Proofreading and general writing advice are not [on-topic](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) here. Can you edit your question to highlight any particular concern?

Comment: In general, I think mentioning that you are not a lawyer would be sufficient.

Comment: If the letter is late, the reader will be keen to get to its actual point. Apologising for the tardiness is probably enough without explanations, unless it is something like "it has taken some time to collect the information."